# Pinch Simulation without Multi touch device

Tags: qt, multi-touch, pinch

I am working on a c++ project in windows OS where I need to simulate multitouch gesture like Pinch without multitouch device.Similar to Iphone where user can simulate pinch by holding option key. 
I want to know whether this can be achieved through Framework like QT ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just zoom or rotate in the mouseMoveEvent, when that modifier is pressed.

I don't think generating actual QTouchEvents is worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you want to navigate the chart timeline with buttons? If so this is what i applied in my project:

```
$("#bt1").click(function () {
var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
var interval = extremes.max - extremes.min;
var enddate = new Date(extremes.max);
var begginingdate = new Date(extremes.min);
enddate = extremes.max - interval;
begginingdate = extremes.min - interval;
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(begginingdate, enddate);});
```

this will scroll your chart to the previous set of data you have on it, with the same timespan you currently have. Eg: if you have data from the 29th of april to the 30th of april displayed on your chart this will move the display to the 28th-29th timespan. If you wish it to move forward just make it `enddate = extremes.max + interval; begginingdate = extremes.min + interval;`

Sorry if this isn't what you were looking for but i truly understood this was what you were asking.

Regards